# Odoo - Show a Overdue Balance Smart button in Res.partner(Customer View)

Tags: odoo

I want to show amount overdue of customer of all invoices in a smart button in Customer View of sales module. I have already developed a smart button same as ***Invoiced*** smart button in Customer View for just a start. But it not showing the same amount as that of ***Invoiced*** Button(always shows 0).

Copied this code in my custom module from partner.view in account

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="partner_view_buttons">
        <field name="name">partner.view.buttons</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
        <field name="priority" eval="20"/>
        <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4, ref('account.group_account_invoice'))]"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <div name="button_box" position="inside">
                <button type="action"
                    class="oe_stat_button"
                    id="invoice_button"
                    icon="fa-pencil-square-o"
                    name="%(account.action_invoice_refund_out_tree)d"
                    attrs="{'invisible': [('customer', '=', False)]}"
                    context="{'search_default_partner_id': active_id,'default_partner_id': active_id}">
                    <div class="o_form_field o_stat_info">
                        <span class="o_stat_value"><field name="total_invoiced" widget='monetary' options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}"/></span>
                        <span class="o_stat_text">Invoiced</span>
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div></field>
    </record>
```

Should I write this(account.action_invoice_refund_out_tree) action also in my module? or will it be called automatically?